# Setting selected item to DropdownList in MVC Application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I am having an MVC application in that I am having an dropdownList on the add client page.
The user selects the sates in the dropdownlists.

On the edit Page,I want the same state selected which the user selected on the add client page please tell what shall I do.

Thank You
Ritz

Answer (score 5):

Try to set selected option at data source (SelectList) like that :

```
Dictionary<string, string> list = new Dictionary<string, string>();
list.Add("State 1", "1");
list.Add("State 2", "2");
list.Add("State 3", "3");
var selectList = new SelectList(list,
          "Value", "Key", 
          "2"); // selected item's value "State 2" is selected.
ViewData["States"] = selectList;

<%= Html.DropDownList("ddlStates", (SelectList)ViewData["States"]) %>
```